# python implementation of mac's doFinal method

Tags: java, python, hmac

I am implementing hmac signature generation in python from some java code which is already written and working.

I tried some hmac generation methods available online for python, but they did not work, and so I am trying to implement the Java logic in Python.

I have almost completed the task, but there is one step at which I am stuck: the doFinal method of mac in java, which processes an input byte array and produces an output byte array after processing it. I have tried a lot of things, but am unable to reproduce the output of java's doFinal method in python. Can anyone please explain how I can implement this method in Python? Or any links providing help for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: pls add your code where you're struggling and maybe what you've tried

Comment: It is not possible for me to add the code as it is organization property. I just have input byte array (obtained from python code) and I need an output byte array (which should be obtained from doFinal method).